# Check how many consecutive times appear in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string

I want to  to display a number or an alphabet which appears mostly
consecutive in a given string or numbers or both.

Example:

```
s= 'aabskeeebadeeee'
output: e appears 4 consecutive times
```

I thought about set the string then and for each element loop the string to check if equal with element set element if so count =+1 and check if next to it is not equal add counter value to list with same index as in set, if is add counter value to li list if value is bigger than existing.

The problem is error index out or range although I think I am watching it.

```
s = 'aabskeeebadeeee'

c = 0
t = list(set(s)) # list of characters in s
li=[0,0,0,0,0,0]  # list for counted repeats
print(t)
for x in t:
    h = t.index(x)
    for index, i in enumerate(s):
        maximus = len(s)
        if i == x:
            c += 1
            if index < maximus:
                if s[index +1] != x:  # if next element is not x
                    if c > li[h]:   #update c if bigger than existing
                        li[h] = c
                    c = 0
            else:
                if c > li[h]:
                    li[h] = c


for i in t:
    n = t.index(i)
    print(i,li[n])

print(f'{s[li.index(max(li))]} appears {max(li)} consecutive times')
```

Comment: I don't think you're going about this the right way. How do you expect "0" to occur in that string? Do you want to get the character which occurs the most times, which would be "e". I don't understand the question

Comment: had to edit, made typo.
Yes, it should print 'e',  s= 'aabskeeebadeeee' output: e appears 4 consecutive times. The last 4 is the longest.

Comment: Oh, it's an easy question that can be done in one pass, let me show you

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space solution, that breaks ties by returning the earlier seen character:

```
def get_longest_consecutive_ch(s):
    count = max_count = 0
    longest_consecutive_ch = previous_ch = None
    for ch in s:
        if ch == previous_ch:
            count += 1
        else:
            previous_ch = ch
            count = 1
        if count > max_count:
            max_count = count
            longest_consecutive_ch = ch
    return longest_consecutive_ch, max_count

s = 'aabskeeebadeeee'
longest_consecutive_ch, count = get_longest_consecutive_ch(s)
print(f'{longest_consecutive_ch} appears {count} consecutive times in {s}')
```

**Output:**

```
e appears 4 consecutive times in aabskeeebadeeee
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex offers a concise solution here:

```py
inp = "aabskeeebadeeee"
matches = [m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'([a-z])\1*', inp)]
print(matches)
matches.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
print(matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
['aa', 'b', 's', 'k', 'eee', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'eeee']
eeee
```

The strategy here is to find all islands of similar characters using `re.finditer` with the regex pattern `([a-z])\1*`.  Then, we sort the resulting list descending by length to find the longest sequence.

Comment: This solution has a time complexity of O(n*logn), making it nonoptimal

Comment: Thank you for that very helpful comment.  I will never use regex for anything, ever again.

Comment: Regex isn't the problem, it's group() and sort(). And you're welcome

Comment: @Mick For large values of `N`, `O(N*lgN)` would give reasonable performance in most settings (unless very high performance would be needed).

Comment: My answer could be improved upon by, instead of sorting the resulting list, just walk down the list once and keep track of the widest string seen.  Then, return that widest string.

Comment: Well guys your solutions are too high level for me, look at mine, is  very simply, the only problem ( I think ) is that I get out of range although I watch it to not to,

Comment: I deleted mine, I didn't realize he wanted consecutive occurrences. Guess your answer beat mine anyway

Comment: @ZiggyWitkowski Your answer is pretty much the textbook answer, good job

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can leverage the power of `itertools.groupby()` to approach this type of problem (for quick counting for similar items in `groups`. [Note, this can be applied to some broader cases, eg. numbers]

```
from itertools import groupby

>>> char_counts =  [str(len(list(g)))+k  for k, g in groupby(s)]
>>> char_counts
['2a', '1b', '1s', '1k', '3e', '1b', '1a', '1d', '4e']
>>> max(char_counts)
'4e'

# you can continue to do the rest of splitting, or printing for your needs...
>>> ans = '4e'      # example
>>> print(f' the most frequent character is {ans[-1]}, it appears {ans[:-1]} ')
```

Output:
the most frequent character is e, it appears 4

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65712212/4) to the question [Check how many consecutive times appear in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65712212) by the OP [Ziggy Witkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14810589) under CC BY-SA 4.0.

> I did not want to use any libraries.
>
> ```py
> s = 'aabskaaaabadcccc'
>
> lil = tuple(set(s)) # Set a characters in s to remove duplicates and
> then make a tuple
>
> li=[0,0,0,0,0,0]  # list for counted repeats, the index of number
> repeats for character
>                 # will be equal to index of its character in a tuple
>
>
> for i in lil:    #iter over tuple of letters
>     c = 0        #counter
>     h= lil.index(i)  #take an index 
>     for letter in s:            #iterate ove the string characters 
>         if letter == i:         # check if equal with character from tuple
>             c += 1              # if equal Counter +1
>             if c > li[lil.index(letter)]:   # Updated the counter if present is bigger than the one stored.
>                 li[lil.index(letter)] = c
>         else:
>             c=0
>             continue
>
> m = max(li)
>
> for index, j in enumerate(li):              #Check if the are
> characters with same max value
>     if li[index] == m:
>         print(f'{lil[index]} appears {m} consecutive times')
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> c appears 4 consecutive times 
> a appears 4 consecutive times
> ```